# How to get value using $_REQUEST in php

Tags: php

This is my web page http `time_zones/time_zones.php?time_zone=+00:00`

in my page i using below code

```
$time_zone = $_REQUEST['time_zone'];
```

but output is  `00:00`
 here `+` sign is not showing...

what i do to get full value from url?

Comment: Please don't use `$_REQUEST` - use the other superglobals instead. In this case, you should use `$_GET`

Comment: can you send it via post?? maybe php convert + in urls to space, if you cant use post so you have to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] => /time_zones.php?time_zone=+00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to encode the plus sign

```
time_zones/time_zones.php?time_zone=%2b00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_zone = htmlentities($_GET['time_zone']);
```

Reference [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the argument.

Change 
'time_zone=+00:00'
to 
'time_zone%3D%2B00%3A00'

Reference:
[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For url you should use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$time_zone = urlencode($_GET['time_zone']);
```